# Counting words using a Binary Tree in Python?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I am not sure how to implement a counter within a binary tree class. As I would like to be able to keep track of the frequency of a word. My issue is that I don't know where to start counting within the insert function.

```
class _Node:
def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
    self._value = value
    self._left = left
    self._right = right
    self._count = 0

class BinaryTree:

def __init__(self):
    self._root = None

def isEmpty(self):
    return self._root == None

def insert(self, value) :
    if self.isEmpty() :
        self._root = _Node(value)
        return
    parent = None
    probe = self._root
    while (probe != None) :
        if value <= probe._value :
            parent = probe
            probe = probe._left

        else :
            parent = probe
            probe = probe._right            

    if (value <= parent._value) :
        parent._left = _Node(value)
    else :
        parent._right = _Node(value)
```

Comment: You have a variable `count`, so find a use for it.

Comment: Is there some reason why you want to use a custom binary tree for this? In Python, it's more usual to use some kind of `dict` for tasks like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want an extra condition on the `if`/`else` you're checking inside the `while` loop in `insert` that handles the situation where the `value` you're inserting is equal to `probe._value`. Something like:

```
if value == probe._value:
    probe._count += 1
    return
elif value < probe._value:
    # the rest as before
```

You also probably want your `_Node` class to initialize `_count` to `1` rather than `0`.

Comment: Thanks. What if you wanted to count only words that show up once.

Comment: Um, by definition, words that only show up once, show up exactly once. There's no counting required.

Comment: Traverse the tree and print the `_value`s of nodes that have `_count == 1`? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: These follow up questions are getting further and further from your current question. Please ask separately if you have more issues you need help with.